# Python Keyboard library not suppressing keystrokes on Linux

Tags: python, keyboard, keyboard-events, hotkeys, keyboard-hook

I am making a script that remaps a single key (right-ctrl) into `alt+tab` using the `Python` library known as [`keyboard`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard). This was easy to do with `Autohotkey` on `windows`, however, this doesn't seem to be possible on `Linux`. After all in the `keyboard` documentation they have `funcion(param, param,` **`Suppress=False)`**, so it should work right?

```py
import keyboard

def altTab:
    keyboard.release(97)
    keyboard.send("alt+tab")

# 97 is the key_code for [right ctrl] on my system
keyboard.on_press_key(97, altTab, suppress=True)
```

I've tried releasing the key from the code standpoint but it doesn't seem to work, as `ctrl+alt+tab` is different from `alt+tab`. I have also tried using the `keyboard.remap_key` function to change `right ctrl` into `right alt`, and `right alt` into `left alt` so that `right alt` would work, then sending just `tab` instead of `alt+tab` but it still doesn't work. I am using `Ubuntu Linux`.
Please help, I'm stumped

Answer (score 3):

You need `hook_key`, that is the method to call provided callback every time provided key is pressed:

```
import keyboard

def altTab(e):
    if e.event_type == "down":
        keyboard.release(97)
        keyboard.send("alt+tab")

# 97 is the key_code for [right ctrl] on my system
keyboard.hook_key(97, altTab, suppress=True)
```

Edit: added code to deal with key press only.

Comment: while this does work, it is basically the same thing as doing `keyboard.on_release_key` which is not what I want, I need `keyboard.on_press_key`, so thanks, but this isn't quite what I was looking for

Comment: this answer also doesn't work for me because it triggers both on press (but doesn't work obviously) and on release (which is not what I want)

Comment: [Docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/README.md#keyboardhook_keykey-callback-suppressfalse) says it handles both. test and change the altTab method for your needs.

Comment: Still doesn't work bro, this is a sloppier (not to be rude or anything) version of `keyboard.on_press_key` (which is not a single time thing like you have said)

Comment: I've looked into `pynput`, however, it requires an active `X server`... I am trying to achieve this *Without* using an `x server`